# Split view controller must be root view controller

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Whenever I try to present a UISplitViewController modally the application crashes. Thus it must allways be the root view controller. Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: Just for reference, I think this is the way to go: See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19983002/1134595

Answer (score 21):

From the [Apple iPad Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/UserInterface/UserInterface.html):

> The split view controller’s view
>   should always be installed as the root
>   view of your application window. You
>   should never present a split view
>   inside of a navigation or tab bar
>   interface.

So yes, you cannot present a split view outside of your main application window (that includes modally).

**EDIT**

The link to the docs above no longer discusses this topic. Relevant discussion can now be found at Apple's [View Controller Catalog for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html), which states the following:

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create. In other words, you must always install the view from a UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s window. [...] Split view controllers cannot be presented modally.

Comment: have you tried it? It says "should" not "must". And presenting a splitview modally in fullscreen mode is whether inside of a navigation nor a tab bar interface. That doesn't indicate that it wouldn't be possible in general.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but given the fact that Apple recommends not doing it, and that you're experiencing issues with it, it would probably be a better idea to rethink your design. If you want a split view type setup, it would be simple to create your own "split view" setup (rather than UISplitViewController) in Interface Builder and present that modally.

Comment: If you try to present a split view modally, you'll get an uncaught exception: "Application tried to present a Split View Controllers modally" [sic]

Comment: What happens if you catch the exception and continue?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem with the same error when I tried to segue from a regular content view controller (ie. no problem segueing from a tab controller or a nav controller).

Fortunately I found a way to circumvent this by inserting a nav controller between the VC and the split view controller.  In other word, segue from the VC to a nav controller, then draw a relationship connection between the nav controller and the split view controller.  In this way, instantiating a split view still requires no coding.

Comment: I found that in this solution - inside a Storyboard - the segue from the VC to the nav controller should be a Modal segue.

Answer (score 2):

Of course u can use `UISplitViewController` without using it as root view controller.
In my project, I use it like this:

1. Show my own viewcontroller in modal method:

```
[self presentModalViewController:mainViewController animated:YES];
```

1. In the mainViewController, I have

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController;
```

and in `- (void)viewDidLoad`, set the `splitViewController.view` to `mainViewController.view`

```
splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];
self.view = splitViewController.view;
```

Comment: That way you won't get messages from the Split View Controller's delegate, though.

Answer (score 1):

The UISplitController CAN BE installed under UITabBarController. I do it. Just use search on this forum - I found at least one good software sample.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Exactly you will have to use RootViewController and it should be inherited from UITableViewController. You may take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.mindyourcode.com/ios/adding-interactive-splitview-for-ipad/)