# UISplitViewController: Why should I never present it inside of a navigation or tab bar interface?

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

From Apple: "You should never present a split view inside of a navigation or tab bar interface."

They don't say why, and they only say "should" not. What would happen if I do it? I can imagine so many good use cases where I would want to!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application may crash. The UISplitViewController was designed to be the root view controller in the VC stack.

SO Question:
[Split view controller must be root view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579861/split-view-controller-must-be-root-view-controller)

Also, as stated in the Class Reference:

> The split view controller has no
>   significant interface of its own. Its
>   job is to coordinate the presentation
>   of its two child view controllers and
>   to manage the transitions among
>   different orientations.

Comment: The statement in the CRef doesn't explain why it would be bad :) It would be theoretically no problem to have some kind of controller managing two views laying out next to eachother inside a root view controller of an navigation controller.

Comment: As an iOS developer, I have realized that Apple doesn't always explain everything they do or why they do it; we just have to roll with it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213097/best-way-to-switch-between-uisplitviewcontroller-and-other-view-controllers) which is related. As Evan notes, usually you just have to roll with Apple's damands. I tried to work around their restrictions; it failed horribly. UISplitViewController is extremely fragile if you do anything Apple don't want you to.