# Using UISplitViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to add a split view controller when the login button is clicked on the login screen (when user is successfully logged in). I want to show another view controller which is a split view controller with a master controller and detail controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SplitViewControllers are intended to be used as the root view controller. So you will need to  create your login viewController and attach it to the window. Then when the user logs in you will have to remove the login viewController and then create a new SplitViewController and attach that to the window instead.

If you search you should find threads that help e.g.

[How to implement SplitViewController on second level.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816670/how-to-implement-splitviewcontroller-on-second-level)

I know there are also threads showing how to do this for tabBarControllers and the process is the same.