# ModalView Over SplitView with transition

Tags: ipad, animation, modal-dialog, transition

My app should display a login modal view, and once authentified, redirect on a SplitView.

For now, i'm using the method that change the rootView in the app delegate. So, in the loginController, i do this :

```
[[[[UIAppDelegate window ] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
```

And after that, i load my splitViewController and place it in the rootViewController property.

It's working. But i would like to make a transition between the two views, and i've absolutely no idea how to make this happen.

Any clue ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this question [Best way to switch between UISplitViewController and other view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213097/best-way-to-switch-between-uisplitviewcontroller-and-other-view-controllers)

It seems that you should show login view as a modal view over split view

Comment: A little late, but yes, the way explained could perfectly work. You could also switch the rootView directly in the main.m. A lot less cleaner.