# how to present a login, with UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to build a universal iOS app. So, in Xcode I started with a Master-Detail template.

In the iPhone version of this, my first view is a list of items, and I have a "Logout" button in my Navigation Bar. When the user launches for the first time, a view-controller is presented, modally, on top of my normal "master" view. It just asks for a user/pass, lets the user log in. If the user hits the "Logout" button, some cleanup occurs, and then they are presented with the Login screen again.

On the iPad side of things, I'd like to have a UISplitViewController - as that interface matches well with what I'm trying to do. I'd like to do this in a similar fashion -- present the user with Login the first time they launch. Then later on, if they decide to leave the app, they can hit Logout, and be presented with Login options again.

I'd prefer to cover the entire screen with one view (just user/pass/login button), but am having trouble figuring that out, especially if the "master" view is visible.

So, the question is this: what is the preferred way to show a login screen, with a UISplitViewController in the mix, so that the user can't do anything else but login?

Comment: [Here][1] is how I handled this kind of situation, hope that helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213097/best-way-to-switch-between-uisplitviewcontroller-and-other-view-controllers/25979945#25979945

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like a personal choice/design decision.

You could have the "master" view be the login screen and have the "detail" be just a splash screen or cute kitten photo that says "please login"

You could also have a single UIView be the "initial" view page and have that segue into the splitview

I think you're quite open in the "how" of it so perhaps I'm not quite understanding your question.

Comment: (sigh) I realize that I may be asking a question without a simple answer here, so I'm pleading with the SO gods to not kill this question. Several people on this site have had trouble with showing a login view with a split-view controller. What I want is a full-screen view to cover the entire split-view, even if the master view is showing. Other people want that, too. But there doesn't seem to be a clear consensus on this, and it may not be the best idea, anyway. So perhaps the approach is wrong. So, what might be the best, non-hacky way to show a login view on top of a split view?

Comment: This might be a question of terminology.

When using the Master-Detail splitview, the entire 2-view set is called the "Splitview". The smaller left hand side is called the MasterView and the larger left-hand side is called the DetailView. From what I understand you are saying you want a view to cover the whole shebang, but then you say even if the master view is showing, so maybe you just want something covering the detail view?

Comment: I accidentally mixed up my left and right. To be clear: Master = smaller on left, detail = larget on right