# Navigation between view controllers in master-detail application

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am new to IOS development. I am developing small application using master-detail application template. The navigation model I am trying to achieve for my app is the following:
before going to split view controller I would like to have view controller where user can make some choices. In that view controller I have few buttons. I can achieve this for iPhone app, but I have not idea how to implement this for iPad app. For iPad when I add navigation view controller and view controller before split view controller I get an error.
My question is: is it possible to add view controller before split view controller in master-detail application (for iPad), or there is another solution for implementing such kind navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Due to Apple's guidlines, the `UISplitViewController` must be the root view controller for your application. If you want to have other views on top of this view, you must present them modally. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213097/best-way-to-switch-between-uisplitviewcontroller-and-other-view-controllers?lq=1) should start you down the right path in doing that.