# Accessing root view controller in AppDelegate start up

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

In our AppDelegate application method we're accessing the root view controller:

```
let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
.... set variables on splitViewController
```

Then after successfully logging in we redirect to the root view controller:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as UIViewController
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But it seems that this login process is wiping out the variables that were set in step #a.  Presumably as in step #b we're recreating the controller.  How can we redirect without wiping out the variables set in #a?

Comment: That means you want to change the root view controller on login success?

Comment: I just want to initialize the root view controller at start up.  And then redirect to it after Login.

Comment: If its rootViewcontroller why do you need to redirect..Since you are accessing the splitViewController as rootViewController, i think its set in storyboard.App loads the splitViewController at startup..

Comment: At start up we redirect to a login controller if the user hasn't logged in.  After Login we then redirect to root.

Comment: Don't do that...You need to set the loginViewController as the rootViewController and on login successful present the splitViewController. From next time,you check if use is logged in. If yes, you just present the splitViewController from Login may be in viewWillAppear method or from appdelegate making user unaware he just came through LoginVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We followed the approach of switching the root view controller when required.  We launch the app and if user is not logged in we set the root to LoginViewController.  After logging in we set the root back to UISplitViewController.  The solution is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25979945/47281