# UISplitViewController pushed from UITabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

In my app I'd like to have only one storyboard for both iPad and iPhone.
My root controller is a `UITabBarController` with 7 children, most are `UISplitViewController`.

On the iPhone the More tab appears automatically to get access to all tabs, making them pushed from there, thus resulting in an error:

```
Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021210/ios-uisplitviewcontroller-cannot-be-pushed-to-uinavigationcontroller

May be this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in a nutshell, what I finally went for is to create my `UISplitViewController`s programatically when the user's device is an iPad while keeping most of my storyboard the same.

to do that:

- In IB, I removed all the viewcontrollers from my `UITabBarController` (the links)
- I gave each of these `UIViewController`s a Storyboard ID
- In the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of the AppDelegate, I created a method to build the hierarchy of my views, using the storyboard ID to instantiate the ViewControllers, and adding a UISplitViewController when being on an iPad. All of this is done in association with a datasource object that fine tunes the needs of each of my screens.

Hope that helps!