# iOS 5.1 Monotouch View Qustions

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to have the following "view" structure?

1) RootViewController is a UITabBarController.
2) One of the "Tabbed" views is a UISplitViewController.
3) The "Detail" view of the "SplitViewController" is a UINavigationController.

What I'm trying to accomplish is the "Detail" view can create a sub view that has a "back" button.

The problem is calling PushViewController(newView, true) in my "Detail" view never displays the newView.

Answer (score 2):

A `UISplitViewController` must the the top level controller.

See here: [Split view controller must be root view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579861/split-view-controller-must-be-root-view-controller)

Instead of using a `UITabBarController` at the root, you should just use the split controller.

The detail and master sections will both have `UINavigationControllers` where you can push as many new screens as you need.