# Show Split View Controller from View Controller

Tags: ios, swift3, uisplitviewcontroller

I just a need a help regarding about split view controller.In my app i need to show split view controller from a view controller (iPad).In my knowledge there is no way to push that split view controller.I have tried like set as a root view controller its working but, i have to go back to previous view controller is the problem.How can i achieve that?. Any solution will be appreciated.

```
    let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SplitViewController") as! SplitViewController



    if vc.splitViewController?.collapsed == true {
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        // UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0].rootViewController = vc

    }
```

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579861/split-view-controller-must-be-root-view-controller